# Java Terminating Before Timer Runs

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timer

I have the following code

```
new Timer(300, this).start();
```

and this

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   //do something
}
```

in the same class which implements `ActionListener`.

The problem is that the program terminates before the code in `actionPerformed` gets chance to run. At least I think that is what is happening!

How do I tell java to keep running when it has nothing to do?

Thanks!

**Edit**: It's a javax.swing.Timer

Comment: What is causing your program to terminate? Is this a Swing or AWT program, or something else? Unless you are explicitly exiting (or closing the main windows and have enabled exit on close), most likely the program is terminating because of an uncaught exception somewhere.

Comment: There is no gui and everything is running in one thread (except for `ActionPerformed` I guess).

Comment: If you don't have a gui, why are you using Swing, and what is triggering calls to `actionPerformed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Timer` uses daemon `Thread`s - they do not prevent the program from exiting.

You using the `javax.swing.Timer` but it doesn't look like you are running in a `Swing` environment.

You need to use a `java.util.Timer` and make sure you create it with `new Timer(false)`. This will build it with non daemon `Thread`s that will keep the application open.

This means you will need to call `cancel()` on the `Timer` for your application to exit.

Comment: Swing applications don't terminate when there is nothing to do. They sit there waiting for events.

Comment: @TedHopp i guess that answers my question then.

Answer (score 1):

A Java program is terminated whenever all the non-daemon threads are finished. So, keep the main thread running or at least one of the non-daemon threads.

Comment: Thanks! So do I just need to create a thread non-daemon that does nothing then. How would I do that?

Comment: @TomJenkinson Do you have GUI in your program?

Comment: No. I am not using a gui anywhere.

Comment: @TomJenkinson Then don't use `javax.swing.Timer`. Instead, use `java.util.Timer` or even better `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: I'm going to use `java.util.Timer`. Thanks for the help.